# What's the best place to hire a freelance (contract) WordPress developer?

Tags: plugin-development

I'm looking to hire someone for ongoing work. Where should I be looking? I posted on Craigslist, oDesk, and Freelancer.  I'm also going to check out CodePoet.com and jobs.wordpress.net.

Answer (score 2):

Another good WP freelance site is [WPQuestions](http://www.wpquestions.com).

Answer (score 1):

[Elance](http://elance.com) is a great option.

Answer (score 1):

I've had good luck with using [Freelancer.com](http://www.freelancer.com). Elance although probably better I find is overly complicated for a freelancing website.

Answer (score 1):

I've found a lot of good help at http://rentacoder.com

It's free and a little less controlled than other networks, but I find it easier to find the kind of guys I'm looking for there, personally. Elance is a lot of hassle.

I also like odesk and 99designs (if you happen to be looking for theme design/implementation)

Answer (score 0):

There is also http://jobs.wordpress.net/